# UART qt to microcontroller, cannot send data properly

Tags: c++, qt, microcontroller, uart

I have had the same problem multiple times with many different microcontrollers. Today I would like to finally solve this.

The problem:

I am trying to send data from my Qt UI to my mycrocontroller.
Now I am able to send it and my mc receives my data (100% sure).
Every time I send data to my mc a led should blink.
But... At some moment my led blinks and at some moments it doesn't. 
When I only send 'D', there is no problem I can see my led blinking.
But when I send "Hello world D\n", the led doesn't blink.

Why? please

my Qt code:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{  
   //SETS up my serial port
            serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
            serialPort->setPortName("COM13");
            serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);

            if (!serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
            {
             qDebug("some error when opening\n");
            }

}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    if(ui->radioButton->isChecked()==true)
    {
       serialPort->write("Hello world D\n"); //doesn't work fine
    }

    else if(ui->radioButton_3->isChecked()==true)
    {
        serialPort->write(" D\n"); //works fine
    }

}
```

My microcontroller code:

```
void blinkLed()
{

    volatile uint32_t ui32Loop;
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R12;
    ui32Loop = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R;
    GPIO_PORTN_DIR_R = 0x01;
    GPIO_PORTN_DEN_R = 0x01;

    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R |= 0x01;
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }
        GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R &= ~(0x01);
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }
    }
}


void
UARTIntHandler(void)
{


    int j=0;
    int ulStatus=0;


    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        receivedDataQt[j] = UARTCharGet(UART0_BASE);
        if(receivedDataQt[j]=='D')
        {
            gotDataQt=1; //this is a global variable
            break;
        }
    }

    ulStatus = UARTIntStatus(UART0_BASE, true);
    UARTIntClear(UART0_BASE, ulStatus);
    initUART(); //re setup UART after interrupt
}

int main(void)
{

    while(1)
    {
        initUART();
        setUARTinterrupt();

        setupI2c(); 
        setupSensor();

        while(1)
        {
                // communicate with sensor

            if(gotDataQt==1) //when it returns from the interrupt this (global) bit  is set
            {
                blinkLed(); //makes my led 
                gotDataQt=0;
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read 20 characters in your interrupt handler? Drop the for loop and it'll probably work, but you'll need to accumulate your buffer a different way.

Comment: indeed this was the way I was accumulating my buffer. What other ways are there then? 20 was just an arbitrary number

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be you're attempting to read multiple characters in your interrupt handler without checking if more characters are available. The general approach would be code more like the following that reads a single character per interrupt:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 20
volatile int j;

void UARTIntHandler(void)
{
    int ulStatus=0;
    ulStatus = UARTIntStatus(UART0_BASE, true);
    while(UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE))
    {
        char c = UARTCharGet(UART0_BASE);
        if (j < BUF_SIZE)
            receivedDataQt[j++] = c;
        if (c == 'D')
            gotDataQt=1; //this is a global variable
    }
    UARTIntClear(UART0_BASE, ulStatus);
}

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        initUART();
        setUARTinterrupt();

        setupI2c(); 
        setupSensor();
        j = 0;

        while(1)
        {
            if(gotDataQt==1) //when it returns from the interrupt this (global) bit  is set
            {
                blinkLed(); //makes my led 
                j = 0;
                gotDataQt=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is untested and I'm not familiar with the microcontroller you're using so it may need some work to suit your application but a few things to take note of are:

- Check that more characters are available and don't try to re-initialize the UART on each interrupt, that shouldn't be necessary.
- You probably don't want to break out of an interrupt that way because it will skip your code that sets it up for next time.
- Declare `j` and `gotDataQt` as volatile when they can be changed in an interrupt.
- Take a look into the volatile keyword and atomic operations. If you're using an 8-bit microcontroller and 8-bit datatypes normally the operation will be atomic, but say they are 16-bits on an 8-bit micro you might want to disable interrupts while reading / writing in the main code to prevent reading and writing things where only a portion of the data was written when the interrupt occurred.

In general it's best to try and make interrupt routines do as little as possible and avoid any delays and loops within them, so your general approach of using flags and performing LED blinks and the like in the main code is good.

Comment: Thank you very much, i ll test this immediately and have a look at what you said. I am using a cortex M3 32-bit microcontroller

Comment: I think The issue is caused when it returns from the interrupt handler. Because If I put the ledBlink function inside of the handler, it always blinks as expected. So I think when it returns there might be some issue. But which one? How can I check it?  (the interrupt occurs in the middle of an i2c communication.)

Comment: If it solved you issue just ACCEPT the answer. That's not only a good way to thank the aswerer. It also helps users to identify it as a possible solution.